# Привязка к команде, которая находится в родительском источнике данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Имею такой XAML - код:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="292" Margin="52,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242" ItemsSource="{Binding DataDeteriorationSystemModel}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Title}"  Command="{Binding DataContext.AddDataInTable}" >
                    </CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

И такой код c#:

```
public class GeneralViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private GeneralCommand _addDataInTable;

    public ObservableCollection<TableDeteriorationSystemModel> DataTableDeteriorationSystemModel { get; set; } 
    public GeneralCommand AddDataInTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _addDataInTable ??
              (_addDataInTable = new GeneralCommand(obj =>
              {
                  // тут действия
              }));
        }
    }


    public GeneralViewModel()
    {
        DataTableDeteriorationSystemModel = new ObservableCollection<TableDeteriorationSystemModel>();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
...
DataContext = new GeneralViewModel();
```

Всё нормально работает, ListBox заполняется данными, но команда не работает. Понятно почему, источник данных - свойство *DataTableDeteriorationSystemModel*, и я пытаюсь обратиться к команде, которой в этом свойстве нет..если я верно передал мысль, как забиндить команду из родительского источника данных? Пытался так, как в коде выше:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.AddDataInTable}"
```

Но пользы это не принесло. Жду Ваших идей и замечаний, спасибо.

Comment: А замечания - `Height="292" Margin="52,61,0,0"`. Не используйте конструктор для размещения контролов! Научитесь писать Xaml сами. Иначе вы потом начнете ругаться на то, что ваш контент скачет по окну не понятным образом, перекрывает другой, заходит за края и много чего еще.

Comment: Используйте `RelativeSource`, как у меня в топике по ссылке выше

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это пример, всего лишь пример :)